# Check database fields on each request Symfony2

Tags: symfony

What I want to do if when a user loging check if he/she has all fields (user fields) complete in the database.

I can check when they loging those fields and then redirect to the profile view, but once they are in the profile view they still can see the menu, so they can easily go to others options and since they are already loging I cannot check it anymore in this way.

So I though that maybe using the controller Event listener I can check that, so I check is the controller is different to the accountController(which have the view to edit profile) and if is different I can check the fields.

The problem with that approach is in the accountController and in other controller they are twig {%render....%} that fires again the controller event and that give me infinity calls.

What approach would better? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of using the controller event (`kernel.controller`) to check for the fields is correct. In your event handler, you just need to check whether the request is the master request...

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;

class FieldUpdater
{
    /**
     * Updates user's fields
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent $event
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function onCoreController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
     {
         //if this isn't the main http request, then we aren't interested...
         if (HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
             return;
         }

         // update fields
      }
 }
```

This way you won't end up with this being fired on every call to `{% render ... %}`

Comment: Thanks, your idea help me and with some additional code it works